# XML element auto value change

Tags: xml

Hi this is a huge file where I need to change value of element "AccumulatorFactor" equal to element "Price"

Example : Price is 60 in node Prepaid2Prepaid so element "AccumulatorFactor" should also be 60.

```
<NodeCopy><Node>SC14
    <Condition>ServiceClass
        <Comment>SC 14 with access fees of 12500 for 30 days</Comment>
        <Values>14</Values>
    </Condition>
    <Node>Community CUG
        <Node>Prepaid2Prepaid
            <Condition>BooleanOperator
                <Operation>AND</Operation>
                <Condition>NumberList
                    <Type>0</Type>
                    <Number>75</Number>
                </Condition>
                <Condition>CommunityId
                    <Value>1-999</Value>
                </Condition>
            </Condition>
            <Tariff>Rate
                <UnitType>Time</UnitType>
                <Price>60.0
                    <Factor>60</Factor>
</Price>
                <Interval>1
                    <Factor>1</Factor>
</Interval>
                <UpdateType>Active</UpdateType>
                <AccumulatorFactor>0.0</AccumulatorFactor>
            </Tariff>
        </Node>
    </Node>
    <Node>A2A
        <Condition>NumberList
            <Type>0</Type>
            <Number>75</Number>
        </Condition>
        <Node>Price
            <Tariff>Rate
                <UnitType>Time</UnitType>
                <Price>163.2
                    <Factor>60</Factor>
</Price>
                <Interval>1
                    <Factor>1</Factor>
</Interval>
                <UpdateType>Active</UpdateType>
                <AccumulatorFactor>0.0</AccumulatorFactor>
            </Tariff>
        </Node>
    </Node>
    <Node>All Operators
        <Condition>NumberList
            <Type>0</Type>
            <Number>77,78
70
76
2911,1108,1177
79
71
3,4,2
121,185,200,91,888,971,2070,890,913,189
555,809</Number>
        </Condition>
        <Node>Price
            <Tariff>Rate
                <UnitType>Time</UnitType>
                <Price>178.8
                    <Factor>60</Factor>
</Price>
                <Interval>1
                    <Factor>1</Factor>
</Interval>
                <UpdateType>Active</UpdateType>
                <AccumulatorFactor>0.0</AccumulatorFactor>
            </Tariff>
        </Node>
    </Node>
</Node>
</NodeCopy>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you doing this in Java? XSLT1? XSLT2? Some other language?

Comment: How are the `Prepaid2Prepaid` node and the matching `<AccumulatorFactor>` element related structurally? Always as shown in the example, or can they be in different places, and how do you know which two match?  Lots of questions before we can help here.

Comment: tariff has the price and accumulatorfactor i want to change valur of accumulatorfactor in the xml and it should be equal to element  price

Comment: sorry I am totally new to this just trying to reduce manual efforts in changing accumulator factor in the xml

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void OverWriteXMLElement()
     {
        string AppFileurl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Config/GlobalConfig.aspx.cs.xml");
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(AppFileurl);

        string UserFileurl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Config/UserManagement.aspx.cs.xml");
        XmlDocument UserDoc = new XmlDocument();
        UserDoc.Load(UserFileurl);


        XmlNodeList aNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("/Application/PageSetting/Pagination");
        XmlNodeList UNodes = UserDoc.SelectNodes("/UserManagement/PageSetting/Pagination");

        foreach (XmlNode unode in UNodes)           
        {
            XmlNode child1 = unode.SelectSingleNode("PageSize");

            if (child1.InnerText == "" || child1.InnerText == null)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode node in aNodes)
                {
                    child1.InnerText = node.SelectSingleNode("PageSize").InnerText;
                    UserDoc.Save(UserFileurl);
                }
            }
        }
```

You can change xml element of one xml file with the help of another xml file.